# Why does this auto-clicker program stop when it starts clicking?

Tags: python, mouseevent, pynput

I am in the process of writing an auto-clicker that will work by holding down a button. I've checked, I haven't seen anywhere in the python community an auto-clicker that works on this principle.

When the program detects that I press the left mouse button it automatically starts clicking. Then, it detects this clicking as if it was me clicking so the program stops.

I'd like the program to click with a given frequency so long as the left mouse button is pressed, and to stop when it is released. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
import time
import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

start = Controller()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    while mouse.is_pressed("left"):
        start.click(Button.left)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: change the button? make it s or something

Comment: No, I just want the program to start clicking on the left mouse button

Comment: i think there is a fault in your logic because if u use left click as a trigger and left click as the action the moment left click is unpressed( by thr action) thr program will stop

Comment: So how can I make it work?

Comment: change the trigger to something else like while u hold say key a it clicks when u letgo it stops